# A Tau Snug John?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, anagram, poetry

Look to space to see planets eight,
You'd probably waste where's I'd just wait.

Multiply Fifty and Three, Ten Million times,
Tis when evolution made me,
Living in pond scum,
What a great time whoopee.

1773 was important to me,
Twas when a month discovered me,
Please take note for i only live Three,
But take my water and I'll out live even thee.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a

> [Tardigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade)

**Because:**
Look to space to see planets eight/ You'd probably waste where's I'd just wait.

> Tardigrades can survive in space, so they wouldn't "waste" on their way to other planets.

Multiply Fifty and Three One Hundred Million times/Tis when evolution made me
Living in pound scum/What a great time whoopee

> Tardigrade fossils have been dated to 530 Million years ago.

Seventeen 73 was important to me/Twas when a month discovered me,

> They were first discovered in **1773**, by German zoologist Johann **August** Ephraim Goeze.

Please take note for I only live Three/But take my water and I'll out live even thee

> Actually a common misconception about Tardigrades. Pop culture lore says they can live forever if they're dehydrated and then re-hydrated, but in really it's only about 10 years. Under normal circumstances they live for a relatively short time (like most microscopic creatures).

Comment: "Twas when a month discovered me, Please take note for i only live Three"- by this i mean they only live for about 2 to 3 months in favorable conditions. Also when they dehydrate there's a good case that they can survive 80+ years, longer than a humans life. A stretch granted, but still evidence based.

Comment: The title is also an anagram for the discoverer's first 2 names

Answer (score 2):

You are a...

> [Tardigrade!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade)

Look to space to see planets eight,

> They are eight-legged creatures.

You'd probably waste where's I'd just wait.

> They are incredibly resilient, able to survive in places where other creatures would waste away and die.

Multiply Fifty and Three One Hundred Million times,
Tis when evolution made me,
Living in pound scum,
What a great time whoopee.

> Exist in fossils dating back ~530 million years, which seems off by an order of magnitude from the above number?

Seventeen 73 was important to me,
Twas when a month discovered me,

> Discovered in 1773 by Johann **August** Ephraim Goeze.

Please take note for i only live Three,
But take my water and I'll out live even thee.

> Average lifespan is a few months, but they're capable of living much longer (100+ years?) in a dehydrated state.

The title is...

> An anagram for "Johann August", as [frabjrew also mentioned in a comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59414/a-tau-snug-john#comment181830_59420).

Comment: Although you got the right answer, i felt compelled to make DqwertyC's answer as correct as he/she had a detailed explanation and even some constructive criticism. I always feel bad not making the first correct answer and the "Answer" :(

Comment: @car: Your evolutionary age seems way off. I guess I shouldn't have wasted time trying to confirm it. :/

Comment: 50+3 = 53 x 100,000,000 = 530,000,000. I realize that this is difficult to work out in English. Maybe i should add a comma?

Comment: @car: That works out to 5.3 *billion*, not 530 *million*.